# How to enable student discount for Working Copy app?

Tags: working-copy-app

I've noticed Pro features of [Working Copy](https://workingcopyapp.com) are available for free for students on GitHub. Does anyone know how I could apply this benefit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here're the instructions:

- Pro features are available to students for free as part of the [GitHub Student Developer Pack](https://education.github.com/pack?utm_source=github+working+copy)
- Install the app from the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/working-copy/id896694807?mt=8&uo=6&ct=education) on your iPhone or iPad
- In order to use pro features, you have to [verify](https://workingcopyapp.com/education/verify/) (do it on your iPhone/iPad) your GitHub student account
- These pro features normally require a purchase, but are available for free while logged into your student GitHub account.

Always follow up-to-date instructions that are available [here](https://workingcopy.app/education/).

It is a mistake that this isn't clear from the Users' Guide and I will fix that.

Best regards,
Anders (that makes Working Copy)